# How use Leaflet.awesome-markers in a VUE SPA using vue2-leaflet

Tags: vue.js, leaflet, vue2leaflet

I would like to insert “custom” markers into a vue2-leaflet component and I found a very interesting library leaflet.awesome.marker that is fitted for the scope but I don’t know how to import an external library such as this into VUE and how/if it can be integrated into vue2-leaflet.
Any suggestion (better an example code)?
Thanks.